# cant call set pixel on a recycled bitmap (debugging)

Tags: android, bitmap

I've read some things about this problem named in the title, but I can't fix it in my code.
Only the Debugger shows me that 'cant call set pixel on a recycled bitmap' and closes the app.

So It's clear, to get an mutable Bitmap and manage the bitmap right. But where is my mistake?

I hope you can help me.

```
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_localization);
    this.bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.raumstrukturapp);
    this.picture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picture);
    this.picture.setImageResource(R.drawable.raumstrukturapp);  calculatePositioniInPixel(infoccol.getBeaconRoomCollector().getBeaconRoom(0).getBeaconRoomeElements().get(0));
    drawPosition(R.drawable.raumstrukturapp);
}


private void calculatePositioniInPixel(BeaconRoomElement bre) {
    setKSUnit(9, 14);

    this.coordInPixel[0][0] = bre.getElementcoordinates()[0][0] * this.xUnit;
    Log.i("Beacons", "x links oben: " + this.coordInPixel[0][0]);
    this.coordInPixel[0][1] = bre.getElementcoordinates()[0][1] * this.yUnit;
    Log.i("Beacons", "y links oben: " + this.coordInPixel[0][1]);
    this.coordInPixel[1][0] = bre.getElementcoordinates()[1][0] * this.xUnit;
    Log.i("Beacons", "x rechts oben: " + this.coordInPixel[1][0]);
    this.coordInPixel[1][1] = bre.getElementcoordinates()[1][1] * this.yUnit;
    Log.i("Beacons", "y rechts oben: " + this.coordInPixel[1][1]);
    this.coordInPixel[2][0] = bre.getElementcoordinates()[2][0] * this.xUnit;
    Log.i("Beacons", "x rechts unten: " + this.coordInPixel[2][0]);
    this.coordInPixel[2][1] = bre.getElementcoordinates()[2][1] * this.yUnit;
    Log.i("Beacons", "y rechts unten: " + this.coordInPixel[2][1]);
    this.coordInPixel[3][0] = bre.getElementcoordinates()[3][0] * this.xUnit;
    Log.i("Beacons", "x links unten: " + this.coordInPixel[3][0]);
    this.coordInPixel[3][1] = bre.getElementcoordinates()[3][1] + this.yUnit;
    Log.i("Beacons", "y links unten: " + this.coordInPixel[3][1]);
}

...
private void drawPosition(int resID) {
    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.raumstrukturapp);
   mutableBm = convertToMutable(bm);
    for(int i = (int) this.coordInPixel[0][0]; i <=  this.coordInPixel[1][0]; i++) {
        for(int j = (int)(this.coordInPixel[0][1]); j <= (this.coordInPixel[2][1]); j++) {
            if(j > 0) {
                mutableBm.setPixel(i, j, Color.rgb(255, 128, 0));
            }
        }
    }
    this.picture.setImageBitmap(mutableBm);
}

public static Bitmap convertToMutable(Bitmap imgIn) {
    try {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "temp.tmp");
        RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");

        int width = imgIn.getWidth();
        int height = imgIn.getHeight();
        Bitmap.Config type = imgIn.getConfig();
        FileChannel channel = randomAccessFile.getChannel();
        MappedByteBuffer map = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, imgIn.getRowBytes()*height);

        imgIn.copyPixelsToBuffer(map);
        imgIn.recycle();
        System.gc();

        imgIn = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, type);
        map.position(0);
        imgIn.copyPixelsFromBuffer(map);
        channel.close();
        randomAccessFile.close();

        file.delete();

    ...

    return imgIn;
}

...
```

}

Comment: Sorry I can't comment. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22129476/4978534)

Comment: Are you sure something isn't throwing inside the `try` block, so `convertToMutable()` returns early, after the `imgIn.recycle()` call? Btw, there's a `BitmapFactory.Options` field you can set for the `decode*()` methods that will return a mutable `Bitmap` directly, and you don't have to mess with the `convertToMutable()` method at all - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inMutable.

Comment: okay convertToMutable is really unecessary. thank you guys.  now the result is, the picture without setting some pixels in the new color.